# Error when using scikit-learn PCA.score()

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pca

I am using `PCA` (**Principal Component Analysis**) from **sklearn** library. The training sets that I am working with have the following shapes: `X_train: (124, 13), y_train: (124, )`. The test sets have the following shapes: `X_test: (54, 13), y_test: (54, )`.

This is how I am doing the `PCA`:

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

pca = PCA(0.75) #75 % variance retained
X_train_pca = pca.fit_transform(X_train_std)
X_test_pca = pca.transform(X_test_std)

print  X_train_pca.shape, X_test_pca.shape, y_train.shape, y_test.shape

>>> (124, 5), (54, 5), (124,), (54,)
```

To test the goodness of the results obtained from Principal Component Analysis, I use logistic regression first.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
lr = LogisticRegression()
lr = lr.fit(X_train_pca, y_train)
```

And, I use `score` from `LogisticRegression` to find the efficacy of the transformation and the mean accuracy of the fit using test data set:

```
print lr.score(X_test_pca, y_test)
>>> 0.9814814814814815
```

However, when I use `score` from `PCA (sklearn)`, I encounter errors:

```
print pca.score(X_test_pca, y=None)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-217-540210963ed0> in <module>()
----> 3 print pca.score(X_test_pca, y=None)

/Users/username/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/decomposition/pca.pyc in score(self, X, y)
    529             Average log-likelihood of the samples under the current model
    530         """
--> 531         return np.mean(self.score_samples(X))
    532 
    533 

/Users/username/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/decomposition/pca.pyc in score_samples(self, X)
    503 
    504         X = check_array(X)
--> 505         Xr = X - self.mean_
    506         n_features = X.shape[1]
    507         log_like = np.zeros(X.shape[0])

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (54,5) (13,)
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I test the goodness of results of `PCA` in `X_test` (and `y_test`)?

Comment: The basic problem that I see here is to apply the mapping (transform) to both the training set and the test set. You have just done it to train data set.

Comment: @min2bro : Thanks for your answer. But, I am confused. I don't find any error when I use `X_test` and `y_test` in `score` from LogisticRegression ( `lr.score(X_test_pca, y_test)` ). The error happens when I am use `score` from `PCA`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `PCA.score()`, you will need to use the original test data. Currently you are sending `X_test_pca` into it, which is already transformed by it.

For `score()` function in any scikit-learn method, you will need the type of data that you used in `fit()` function. Not the transformed output. `PCA` will automatically transform the original data inside the `score()` method and then calculate the log-likelihood.

Change this:

```
pca.score(X_test_pca, y=None)
```

to this:

```
pca.score(X_test_std, y=None)
```